# Win 10 connected printer is not working with samba

Tags: networking, printing, samba, windows-10

My problem is as simple: I have HP Deskjet 5550 connected to my Windows 10. Printing from Win 10 works. I can't print from my Ubuntu. They are connected in a network. (Prior to this setup I was using a Windows XP where printing was no problem.)

When adding a new printer in Ubuntu, I always get asked for authentification on my Windows PC, but there authentification is turned off. Next, my credentials used on the Windows PC don't work for this authentification dialog (asking for user name, domain and password). Anybody knows what this authentification dialog is for? (Under Win 10, all steps for a working samba configuration have been taken - as far as known)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to create a second user (without spaces in the name) with a password in my Windows. That worked for the authentification.

If printing still doesn't work, enter the credentials in the main dialog for adding a samba printer and avoid using the dialog which asks for creditials every time.